# Unable to process a input file using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Basically I am trying to take a `String` as input through a `Scanner` class.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = new String();
        for(int t=0;t<10;t++)
        {

            if(sc.hasNextLine()) line = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

}
```

Using the inputs

```
ama
asd
asd
asd
fds
fdgd
asd
ghfg
dfs
ghfh
```

what I notice is when I write the input one by one on console I get the correct output. But when I paste the input together I don't get the last output.

How to overcome such a situation.

**It's basically wanting a Enter and then it gives the 10th input's output.**

**Note:** It is something related to codechef's problems. The input will be given altogether and not entered one by one.

Comment: I think I understand what your issue is now.  The reason that the last input is not being processed is because it is lacking the new line character that the rest of them have.  Essentially, you are emulating an Enter press because after each of the inputs (excluding the last one), there is a hidden new line character (in a Unix environment: \n, Windows I believe is: \r).  If you were to copy your input to a text file and go to the last input and hit return, then copy everything including the empty line at the bottom into your console, it should pick up your last input.

Comment: actually i cannot modify the input file,i can only put my code in that site and they will check the output by checking with their input files.

Answer (score 0):

You could tell the Scanner to use a delimiter. But be aware that you only get the next chunk of data when the delimiter turns up after it. This is why you don't get the last output.

So when you use...

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter(" ");
String line = new String();

for(int t=0;t<10;t++){
    if(sc.hasNext()) line = sc.next();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

... with **one** input `"ama asd asd asd fds fdgd asd fghfg dfs ghfh "` (note the space at the end), it should work.

Comment: the input file is a bit different.Sorry for the error.And i am not the one who will decide what will be the output

Comment: @ManojitPaul I see. But without getting a delimiter (be it a newline or a space or whatever) the scanner won't know when it's supposed to output the data. If you use .nextLine(), the delimiter is a newline (Enter pressed). The line is terminated by this. If it's missing, the scanner thinks the line is not complete, yet.

Comment: @ManojitPaul Well, however you do it, the program will always have to know when a singe input is finished. So it needs some kind of delimiter that marks the end of one input. Be it a space or a newline character.